# Group by other table with sum function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that pulls in a delivered count of a campaign. Each run is a new row in the runs table. To retrieve a campaign I need to join the related table in.

```
SELECT c.Company, r.RunId, r.DeliveredCount FROM Run r
INNER JOIN Campaign c ON r.CampaignId = c.Id
WHERE r.RunId = 3001626 AND c.Company LIKE '%74108%'
```

Why does it return more than one row, even when I specify the Run Id I would like to pull?

Comment: It instead returns multiple rows of the same data, which skews when I try to use a SUM function.

Comment: This query will return `r` times `c` records, where `r` is the number of records in `Run` with `RunId` equal to `3001626`, and `c` is the number of records in `Campaign` where `Company` matches `%74108%`. If you want only one instance of any given `Company, RunId, DeliveredCount`, then you can add a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @AakashM applying some logic to determine which row to include for any given combination (or, probably, using an aggregate and `GROUP BY`), is usually going to be much better than just blindly throwing `DISTINCT` on there to hide the underlying problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand oh, absolutely.

Comment: Is `Run (RunID)` unique? Is `Campaign (ID)` unique? If they are both, then the query should return 1 row maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * 
from Campaign  
where CampaignId = 3001626 
AND Company LIKE '%74108%'
```

I suspect you will get more than one row